# Access List from Parent site in the Subsite without going to Parent's quick launch

Tags: list, navigation, custom, launch

I have a custom list built in the parent site and I want to put it on the Quick Launch of a subsite for finance manager to be able to edit this list.  I did these steps:
- added a web page to the finance teams quick launch menu
- added a web link to the custom list on that page

Those step work fine and we can see the custom list on subsite page and we can get to it to do the editing.

The problem is that because the custom list belongs to the parent it switches to the quick launch of the parent site when you go to the list so when the finance manager finishes editing the list she is dumped into the parent menu and no longer sees her finance subsite.

Is there a different way to add this custom list that is not going to change the subsite and quick launch?
This is a non-publishing site on SP 2016

Comment: thanks Ahmad.  I am finally getting back to this project.  I have used your idea for a short term solution - thank you.   I think there must be a way to reset the menu so it reflects the correct subsite  - it probably takes some .js code or something.  I am going to continue looking for a long term solution.  If you have more ideas on this pls send them.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to edit the list view page (Example AllItems.aspx) on the parent site and add a content editor web part CEWP at the top. Create a hyperlink in CEWP that points back to the subsite.